# How to get started and deploy application with Microsoft Dynamics 365 Higher Education Accelerator

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, accelerator

Please let me know that how to get started and deploy application with Microsoft Dynamics 365 Higher Education Accelerator.

I searched a lot but confuse how to start with Microsoft Dynamics 365 Higher Education Accelerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Dynamics CRM instance and then you can install it as solution.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en/product/dynamics-365/mshied.highereducationcommondatamodel?tab=overview&modalAppId=mshied.highereducationcommondatamodel&signInModalType=2&testDrive=true&ctaType=5

Or you can use test drive that will give you access to CRM with the solution installed.

Here is the documentation

https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE4rwFm